# HTML element which defaults to display:inline-block?

Tags: html, css

`<div>` defaults to `block`

`<span>` defaults to `inline`

Is there one that defaults to `inline-block`?

If not, what special tag name would be appropriate for me to apply 'inline-block' using CSS?
Or should I stick to using a class?

Comment: I think there is only one - `<img>`.

Comment: @jack-tuck That is wrong, see answers.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From what I can tell the `<img>` tag is the only `inline-block` by default. To be on the safe side I would recommend a class, you never know when changing all elements of a certain type will come back to bite you. Or, you could always make up your own tag and assign `display:inline-block;` to it. This way you aren't changing the default functionality of standard elements...

**EDIT**

It also appears that `button`, `textarea`, `input`, and `select` elements are also `inline-block`

Sources:

According to this `img` is `inline-block` http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img-display

And here claims that `button`, `textarea`, etc. are as well: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

**EDIT #2**

While the source above claims that `img` tags are `inline-block` it seems (thanks to Alohci) that they are just `inline` http://jsfiddle.net/AQ2yp/

The following were tested in Firefox:

`button` is `inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/GLS4P/

`textarea` is `inline`: http://jsfiddle.net/235vc/

`input` is `inline`: http://jsfiddle.net/RFKe8/

`select` is `inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/5B4Gs/

Comment: It shows how widespread the myth about img been inline-block is. Yet it's easy to test. Just use any browser's dom inspector on an un CSS'd img and you'll see that it is display:inline. Or see this JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AQ2yp/

Comment: @Alohci I guess you're right, just tested in Chrome, FF and IE and all three came up as `inline`

Comment: @DrydenLong you should take into consideration the difference in Web-Browsers

Comment: @DrydenLong please for clarity sake remove the wrong information.

Comment: @Alohci An `<img>` element behaves like inline-block though, because the width and height can be set, which you can't for an inline element and it aligns vertically like an inline-block element.

Comment: @Esger - It's not true that you can't set height and width for an inline element. You can't set the height and width for a *non-replaced* inline element. img is a replaced element, so that limitation does not apply. "inline-block" literally means "inline level, block container". Replaced elements are not block containers, since as they are replaced, they don't contain anything. Nor could they in any way be described as behaving like they were block containers. Their similarity to inline-block elements is limited to their display-outside behaviour, i.e. to their inline-level ness.

Answer (score 24):

> Is there one that defaults to `inline-block`?

Strictly speaking, **no there isn't**. The W3 HTML specifications do not ever specify default CSS property values for *any* elements. They do provide a ["default style sheet"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) for HTML 4, but developers are only *encouraged* to use it - it is not a requirement or any sort of mandate. The HTML 5 specifications indicate "typical default display properties" but, again, those are not required (also keep in mind that HTML 5 is still a *working draft* anyways).

So that leaves all default values up to the browser and how the developers actually feel elements should be displayed to a user. No one can guarantee that a specific element will display as `inline-block` or any other way in someone's browser. **You should always explicitly set that if you want it to happen.** Don't rely on "defaults."

> If not, what special tag name would be appropriate for me to apply 'inline-block' using CSS? Or should I stick to using a class?

This is up to you and how you are designing your pages. You should always use elements that are semantically appropriate to the content contained within them. If the element will *always* be used in a context which will require `inline-block` display, by all means set it to that in your style sheet. Otherwise, you will have to resort to classes or more specific selectors in order to make your elements display properly.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Fiddle that gets the default display value for a majority of HTML tags.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgyxs/3/)

In chrome, the default inline-block elements are: `"INPUT", "BUTTON", "TEXTAREA", "SELECT"`

Comment: Nice, +1. In Firefox it's only `button` and `select`. IE 11 has all 4 as `inline-block`

Answer (score 5):

My solution to this is declaring what I call a `slice`.

**CSS**

```
sl {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Usage**

```
<sl>inline block stuff</sl>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/avernikoz/pen/LdGOpp) with all HTML elements and their `display` property by default. *Some tags are syntax-broken, but it does not matter for our purpose.*

Currently, there are **5** elements with `display: inline-block` in **FF** :

1. `<button>`
2. `<select>`
3. `<meter>`
4. `<progress>`
5. `<marquee>`

And additional **2** *(including 5 above)* in Chrome:

1. `textarea`
2. `input`

Answer (score 3):

In principle, it depends on the browser what the default value for the `display` property is for each element. Even HTML5 drafts do not prescribe what values must be used, though it presents “expected rendering” of elements in terms of CSS.

According the [default style sheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) for HTML in the CSS 2.1 specification, the elements that have `display: inline-block` by default are `button`, `input`, `select`, and `textarea`. Browsers use such settings, except that in Firefox, this only applies to `button` and `select`.

In the [Rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html) section of HTML5 CR, the `meter` and `progress` elements are additionally describes as having inline block as “expected rendering”, and browsers that have implemented these elements appear to behave that way. The `keygen` element is also described as being an inline block, but Firefox does not do that (it implemented `keygen` internally as `select` in the DOM); IE does not support `keygen` at all; Chrome implements it as suggested.

Since all of these elements have rather specialized meanings, functionality, and rendering idiosyncracies, none of them is adequate for general use as an element that is an inline block by default and may have various meanings. What you can use for such an element is normally `span` or `div`, depending on whether you prefer inline or block as the default rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can create a Custom Element (for example: `<inline-block>` or whatever) that will have its CSS property `display` set to `inline-block` by default.

```js
customElements.define( 'inline-block', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `<style> :host { display: inline-block } </style>
                          <slot></slot>`
    }
} )
```

```css
#hw { background-color: lightblue }
```

```html
<inline-block id="hw">Hello World</inline-block>
```

Answer (score 1):

`button`, `textarea`, `input`, and `select` default to `inline-block`.

In the event you would want to `inline-block` a `div` you'd give it a class name.

```
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Then...

```
<div class="inline-block"></div>
```

**CORRECTION**

I was mistaken about `img`. It seems it defaults to `inline` and not `inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a true answer to the question right now, but with enough support, it may someday be.

`<seg>` short for "segment".  As in, segments of a line.

with the polyfill:

```
<style> seg { display: inline-block; } </style>
```

It really would be nice if there was an official one, but there is not, so here is the best (IMO) suggested name for such an element that I know of.

Answer (score -14):

YES there is an element that defaults to inline.

The answer is the span element.

```
<span>
```

Comment: OP was asking for `inline-block` not `inline`

Comment: ahh didn't catch that.

Comment: If you are using inline-block elements, beware with IE! you need to apply zoom:1 to have it cross browser compatible with IE. You've been warned

Comment: Aside from being the wrong display value, this is also rather useless anyways. *All* elements which do not otherwise have a display property set in the browser's default style sheet will be displayed inline - it's the initial value for that property.