# Does an HTML tag exist that is defaulted as an inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I'm well aware of applying display: inline-block; in CSS, but I'm curious if there is a HTML tag that displays as inline-block by default. Complementary to div & span.

- div = block
- span = inline
- ??? = inline-block

In the case that there is not a default tag, would be ok to create my own tag?

Ex)

```
<indiv></indiv>


indiv { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: There is a draft about [custom elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/), but their name must contain a dash.

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614938/html-element-which-defaults-to-displayinline-block). Please use a search engine of your choice before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only html elements with default style of inline block are **button, textarea, input, and select** . About creating your own tag, there are ways to do it, but think that most browsers will miss it.

Additionally, you can play with rarely used elements, like `hr` or `i`. Simply change the attributes for these elements and make them work as you want. This is very common in Bootstrap, where th `<i>` tag is used to display icons in the nav

By the way, can't understand why when you can simply add a class to any element, apply the inline-block style and be a happy man. But well, there goes the answer to your question.

Note: `Marquee` is also an inline-block element, but it's obsolete in HTML5. However, if you are one of those still using HTML4.x or XHTML, maybe it's of use

Comment: Primarily I just want something cleaner using a generic tag without having to add class="inlineblock" to every div I wanted inline.

Also it appears the elements that are inline-block are extremely specific elements, so there isn't really a generic/styleless inline-block element similar to span or div.

Comment: "*the only html elements with default style of inline block are button, textarea, input, and select*" - I guess this answer is based on [Appendix D. Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html), but note that this appendix is informative, not normative. "*Simply change the attributes for these elements and make them work as you want.*" - Do not do that!! HTML is semantic, not presentational! Using some elements because of their styling instead of their meaning is bad.

Comment: I'm sure the millions of sites using Bootstrap are bad, but they still work, so the answer is still correct. As a matter of fact, I assume there must be like 1% of the total existing sites with "correct" coding. And it's probably a reach. Most advanced sites are way "incorrect". Simply the technology hasn't reached that state and those "incorrect" sites will be the norm in 3-4 years.

Comment: @NickCarson and yes, you're correct, they're really specific, hence why I recommended adding a class. Or do the other options I mentioned at your own risk, of course

Comment: @Fabio what are the downsides of using a custom tag? I'm not targeting old browsers like IE7/8

Comment: well, you risk browsers not be able to understand your code. I'm not only talking about old browsers (and no matter what you target, there's a chance a percentage of people will use them), but also future developments of browsers. This being said, I don't consider there's an unique way to do things, and if it works, it works, so maybe try it by yourself and see how it works out for you, I'm just telling what I'd do (well, what I wouldn't). On the other side, nobody ever created anything new by following the rules so...

Comment: On a side note, one of my pet peeves with bootstrap is the corruption of the `<i>` element. It has a semantic meaning in HTML5 which has nothing to do with icons: http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/