# HTML a list of all elements native CSS display values?

Tags: html, css

Is there an updated list of all HTML elements display properties (inline-block, block, inline)?

For instance, `div` is a block element, `span` is an inline element, etc. I imagine there would a spreadsheet of all this information for items like `textarea`, `h1`, `p`, etc

I can't seem to find a table / spreadsheet with all the html elements out there though

The only thing I could find was this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614938/html-element-which-defaults-to-displayinline-block) on stackoverflow

Comment: for css2.1/html4 there is https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default CSS Values for HTML Elements
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Comment: As an add-on, anything showing `(internal value)` is defined by the vendor, but is typically pretty consistent.