# How do HTML5 and CSS3 specs decide the display attribute of a div element?

Tags: css

The web (especially frontend) technology evolves so fast that I have to re-learn it literally every year, this time being a (seemingly) ridiculously easy question：why does `div` has `display: block`?

Traditionally we have block and inline level elements, defined directly in [HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3), but HTML5 [replaced that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#block-level_vs._inline) with concepts like flow content and phrasing content, which according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) leaves this presentational characteristic to CSS. This makes perfect sense following the principle of separation of concerns.

But what does CSS3 say on `div`? The [display module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/) spec primarily discusses the box layout, where the default/initial value for `display` is `inline`. It also references [CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) occasionally for flow layout. Unfortunately CSS2 (including [CSS2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-boxes)) seems using the term "block-level elements" directly, as if they are already defined somewhere else.

Besides, there are concepts like block formatting context, block boxes, etc. But I feel they are not directly related to the determination of `display` value for `div`.

At the end of the day, I just don't how rendering of `div` works in latest HTML/CSS specs.

Comment: it's not the Spec but browser default styles (user agent)

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21636061/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif - That's not practically true. The HTML5 spec rendering section [15.3.3 Flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#flow-content-3) states that `div` elements are [expected](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#rendering) to be `display:block`.

Comment: @Alohci well, we still learn new things :) I didn't expect to have CSS related things in the HTML spec. Worth adding an answer I guess.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Don't forget to award the bounty to an answer ! In 4  hours, these 50 reputation points will be lost !

Comment: @Programmer not they won't, I still have a 24h grace period after the 4 hours ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default styling for the elements is described in the [Rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#rendering) section of the HTML5 specification.

Browsers are not required for conformance to follow the rules described there but in most cases they do. For elements as well established as `div`s, it would make no sense not to follow them.

`div` elements belong to a [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#flow-content-3) set that are set as `display:block`

```css
address, blockquote, center, dialog, div, figure, figcaption, footer, form, 
header, hr, legend, listing, main, p, plaintext, pre, xmp {
    display: block;
}
```

It's worth noting that several of these elements are obsolete - `center`, `listing`, `plaintext` and `xmp`. They should not be used by authors but their rendering is still defined so that old web documents will still render correctly.